# Swagger 2 Use fields instead of getters+setters

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have the following java REST service

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{customerId}")
    @Operation(
            summary = "Test summary",
            description = "Test desciption",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            content = @Content(
                                    schema = @Schema(implementation = CustomerDto.class),
                                    mediaType = "application/json"),
                            description = "CustomerDto description"),
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "400",
                            description = "Description for 400 status")
                    //Here you can add all response statuses and their's descriptions
            })
    public CustomerDto findCustomerById(@Parameter(description = "Id of the customer", required = true) @PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) {

        return apiFacade.getCustomerDtoByCustomerId(customerId);
    }
```

Simple dto-class

```
    public class CustomerDto {

        private TestInfo testInfo;

    }
```

Simple subclass

```
public class TestInfo {
    private Long testId;
    private Long checkId;

    public TestInfo(Long testId, Long checkId) {
        this.testId = testId;
        this.checkId = checkId;
    }

    public Long getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }

    public Long getCheckId() {
        return checkId;
    }

    public boolean isDecisionMade() {
        return testId != null || checkId != null;
    }
}
```

I'd like to see TestInfo-json without 'decisionMade' section. Can you help me It is possible?

```
      "TestInfo" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "testId" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "format" : "int64"
          },
          "checkId" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "format" : "int64"
          },
          "decisionMade" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
```

Is it possible to tell swagger use class-fields instead of getter+setter?
I use swagger version 2.2.2. Generate json via BaseOpenApiResource. All configs are default.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the decision:

```
        Json.mapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        Json.mapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```